# Debian and Nvidia driver don't get along?

Tags: debian, drivers, nvidia, proprietary-drivers

In a Lenovo z40-70 I've installed Debian Jessie. For customization purposes I've installed `nvidia-detect` through console. Then ran

```
nvidia-detect
```

and I got

```
No NVIDIA GPU detected.
```

These were my steps:

```
# su
# apt-get update
# apt-get install nvidia-detect
# nvidia-detect
"No NVIDIA GPU detected"
```

Am I doing something wrong? I don't get why is giving me that answer, when I checked on

```
hardinfo --> PCI --> Nividia GPU
```

the system is able to detect it.

Comment: Show `lspci -nnk | grep "VGA\|'Kern'\|3D\|Display" -A2 `

Answer (score 0):

Linux (Debian, Ubuntu) have trouble if you have graphics card (esp. hybrid graphics card = intergrated graphics + standalone Nvidia card).

E.g. I could not use/detect Nvidia graphics card on my new Zbook on Ubuntu 16.04. So I set `--nomodeset` and `--apci=off` arguments in the boot config.

Esp. if you have installed the latest Linux (e.g. Jessie which was just released) on a new laptop, chances are it won't recognize the graphics card. Did you have any problems getting your display to run after you installed Linux?

Comment: Linux does not have trouble if you have graphics card, what a ridiculous statement given all the NNs trained on it. The only problem is with hybrid graphics card setup, esp. optimus.

Comment: This is based on my exp running (or trying to) Ubuntu 14.04 and 16.04 on two laptops with an Nvidia graphics card and another one (the zbook) with hybrid graphics (again, with Nvidia). In the first case I actually wanted the GPU for CUDA, but I had display issues and purging the drivers didnt work (had to change the boot params). I've run Ubuntu on high-end PCs with GPUs so I knw it works. Maybe you tried something diff. Maybe I should've been more specific in my ans. In any case you should give constructive feedback and not insult others' experiences, when this might actually help someone!